# As an F1 student, do I need CPT status if I'm working outside of the US?

Tags: usa, visa

I'm doing my PhD and will be starting an internship in the UK (and have EU + Canadian citizenship).

Do I need CPT status for this internship? I'm not sure whether CPT/OPT is only for F1 students working in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

US immigration status is only for people present in the US. So no, US CPT has no meaning outside of the US.

Comment: That's correct - no CPT needed for people on F1 visas working outside of the US. (Just confirmed with the international center at my school too - thanks!)